# How can I use embedded jetty to simulate proxy server?

Tags: java, servlets, proxy, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have `i` proxies, each with different ip `host_i`.

I want to make requests to

`<host_i>:4444/content` go to

`localhost:9999/content?proxy=<host_i>`

How do I do this? Here's what I have so far trying to use embedded jetty server (version: 8.1.10.v20130312), but it doesn't work and I can't figure this out. I got this example from: http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-servlets/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/AsyncProxyServer.java?h=jetty-8

```
    proxyServer = new Server();
    Connector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
    connector.setPort(4444);
    proxyServer.setConnectors(new Connector[]{connector});

    ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();
    proxyServer.setHandler(handler);

    ServletHolder proxy = handler.addServletWithMapping("org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.ProxyServlet", "/");
    proxy.setAsyncSupported(true);

    proxyServer.start();
```

This is my code using simpleframework that handles requests to `localhost:9999`:

```
    websiteContainer = new HttpServer();
    websiteServer = new ContainerServer(websiteContainer);
    websiteConnection = new SocketConnection(websiteServer);
    final SocketAddress websiteAddress = new InetSocketAddress(9999);
    websiteConnection.connect(websiteAddress);

    public class HttpServer implements Container {
    @Override
    public void handle(final Request request, final Response response) {
            // do some stuff here, I have a breakpoint here to test if a request to a proxy made it here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void handle(final Request request, final Response response) {
// building redirect url localhost:9999/content?proxy=<host_i>

 redirectUrl= "localhost:9999/" + httpRequest.getContextPath() + "? proxy =" + httpRequest.getLocalAddr();            
// do remaing stuff here
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem as `httpRequest.getContextPath()` gives you IP of where your app is running and `httpRequest.getContextPath()` gives you contaxt path whish is hit